# UITableViewCell Image not loading

Tags: uitableview, firebase, swift3, firebase-storage

I want to download images from firebase storage and load it in the tableview but it is not working.
My `downloadUrl` is right and there is no error.

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downloadURL) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {
                cell.imageView?.image = downloadedImage
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is not working? Do you have an error?
Have you tried using breakpoints to see what fails in the process? Is the cell null ? Is the image empty? Could you elaborate on what you *know* is fine and where you believe the problem starts. With that we can start to work something out :)

Comment: Cell is not null and Image is not empty and I have no error. I want to show image in my tableview but image is not showing.

Comment: Try printing your image in dispatch or something else, and see if you are able to print it..

Comment: It prints image's url

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use Firebase Storage's [built in download mechanisms](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files) for this?

```
let httpsReference = FIRStorage.storage().referenceForURL('https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/b/bucket/o/images%20stars.jpg') // your download URL
httpsReference.dataWithMaxSize(1 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) -> Void in
  if (error != nil) {
    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
  } else {
    // Data for "images/stars.jpg" is returned
    let starsImage: UIImage! = UIImage(data: data!)
    cell.imageView.image = starsImage // by default, callbacks are raised on the main thread so this will work
  }
}
```